# How to decrypt a RSA message with private and public exponent and modulus in PHP?

Tags: php, rsa

I have an RSA encrypted message, the private and public exponent and the modulus. How can i decrypt the message with PHP? The exponents and the modulus are base64_encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post: http://stevish.com/rsa-encryption-in-pure-php

It uses the PHP RSA Pear extension.